# couple of problems in my ubuntu software

Tags: software-center, gnome-terminal, python3

1.I have updated the oracle virualbox
2. updated the python latest version
3. post doing the update and upgrade some of the applications are disappreed like "software updater", also unable to open the Terminal from activities bar when i press, the cursor is just rotating and closing nothing is coming up even if i press Ctrl+Alt+F2 nothing is working

how to rectifiy and get my ubuntu to working conditions

Comment: Can you clarify what you did when you upgraded python to the latest version?  What version(s) are you running? `python --version` and `python3 --version`

Comment: yes i upgraded to python3 first it upgraded to 3.6 then again 3.8

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubantu-18-04 (64-bit)

Comment: Is python 2 still installed?  I suspect replacing python 3.6 with 3.8 is what broke things.  Downgrade python3 and see if that fixes it, Ubuntu 18 should use 3.6

Comment: yes if i do python3 --version its showing me Phython 3.7.7 & also python -V "Python 2.7.17 & how can i do downgrade means can you give the steps